# Проблема с методом Зейделя

Tags: c#

никак не могу избавиться от костыля: double o=1; while (o >= 0.001) { o = 0;... Что можете посоветовать?

```
double[] Zeidelya(double[,] mat, double[] vls, int dim)
    {

        double[] ans = new double[dim];
        double[] k = new double[dim];
        double sum;

        for (int y = 0; y < dim; y++)
        {
            sum = mat[y, y];
            if (sum == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                return (vls);
            }
            vls[y] /= sum;
            for (int x = 0; x < dim; x++)
                mat[y, x] /= sum;
            mat[y, y] = 0;
            ans[y] = vls[y];
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < dim; y++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < dim; x++)
                sum += Math.Abs(mat[y, x]);
            if (sum >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Данная матрица не приводима к сжимающей");
                return (vls);
            }
        }


        double o=1;
        while (o >= 0.001)
        {
            o = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < dim; y++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < dim; x++)
                    sum += mat[y, x] * ans[x];

                if (Math.Abs(ans[y]-vls[y] + sum) > o)
                    o = Math.Abs(ans[y] - vls[y] + sum);
                ans[y] = vls[y] - sum;
            }

        }

        return (ans);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно сделать так:

```
    while (true)
    {
         double o = 0;

         ...

         if (o < 0.001)
             break;
    }
```